# Derefencing a void function pointer in combination with "&"

Tags: c

While studying the proof of concept for ooc (Object Oriented C) I stumbled onto a piece that I have trouble understanding effect and intention. The book ooc was written by Axel Schreiner who has been retired for a while and indicated he would prefer not to dive into c-code. So I pose my query here.

EDIT: I marked the answer that indicates what I interpreted wrong. +1 for the comment of chux and +1 for the answer of 4386427.

The code in question is:

```
{
    typedef void (* voidf) ();
    voidf selector;
    va_list ap = * app;
    /* generic function pointer */
    while ((selector = va_arg(ap, voidf)))
    {
        voidf method = va_arg(ap, voidf);
        if (selector == (voidf) ctor)
        * (voidf *) & self —> ctor = method;
        else if (selector == (voidf) dtor)
        * (voidf *) & self —> dtor = method;
        else if (selector == (voidf) differ)
        * (voidf *) & self —> differ = method;
        else if (selector == (voidf) puto)
        * (voidf *) & self —> puto = method;
    }
    return self;
}}
```

It's intention is to overwrite inherited functions with specific functions for this class. A call might be

```
if (! PointClass)
    PointClass = new(Class, "PointClass",
    Class, sizeof(struct PointClass),
    ctor, PointClass_ctor,
    0);
if (! Point)
    Point = new(PointClass, "Point",
    Object, sizeof(struct Point),
    ctor, Point_ctor,
    draw, Point_draw,
    0);
```

The interesting bit is code like `ctor, Point_ctor` where both are function pointers (the constructor in this case). The code in question processes the call.

The problem I have with the code is in the lines (case of differ):

```
        else if (selector == (voidf) differ)
        * (voidf *) & self —> differ = method;
```

The last line derefences `voidf *` (where voidf is a generic function pointer, see typedef) and does a *binary* and ('&') with self-> differ and then assigns method to differ.

I get that the `self->differ` function pointer gets overwritten, but:

1. why dereference `voidf *` (voidf is already a pointer)?
2. why do a binary and ('&')? What does it do?

I have tried his examples and they appear to work, but these 2 things I don't understand: can someone help me understand what is going on here?

P.S. I do get a pretty serious compiler warning "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules" probably referring to the derefence of a generic pointer.

Kind regards, Guus.

Comment: Posting additional code before/after the present code snippets would allow others to readily compile the code and accelerate analysis and add clarity.  Example `self , ctor` are 2 identifiers lacking definition.

Comment: Post the type of member `.ctor`.  Is it a function pointer or an  address to a function pointer?

Comment: `* (voidf *) & self —> differ`, I believe is like `* ((voidf *) (&(self->differ)))`.  The `&` is not a `binary and`, but a to take the address of `self->differ`.

Comment: I think you need to learn C as you do not know the basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why dereference voidf * (voidf is already a pointer)?

`voidf` is not a pointer. It is a type. You can't dereference a type.

The `(voidf *)` is a cast.

> why do a binary and ('&')? What does it do?

It is not a "binary and". It is address-of.

So in general you read the code wrong. Read it like:

```
* ((voidf *) (&(self —>differ))) = method;
```

Comment: Yeah, I completely misread the statement. Thanks for the explanation.